# determine if $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{n}{e^n}$ converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

determine if $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{n}{e^n}$ converges. I used the ratio test and eventually came to that: $\frac{n+1}{en}$ which is approximatley equal to $\frac{1}{e}$ which is less than 1. Therefore it converges

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Basically. You would probably be expected to say that $\frac{n+1}{en}$ has **limit** $\frac{1}{e}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Or at least state that the fraction is sufficiently proximate to its approximate.

Comment: @AntonioVargas [OffTopic] How do you create a 4 letter comment?

Comment: @Thomas One option is `${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your method is correct. One can also find the exact sum quite easily in various ways. Here's one example through differentiation:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{x}{1 - x}  = \frac{1}{1-x} - 1 \qquad \text{for $|x| < 1$}$$

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2} \qquad \text{differentiating both sides}$$

$$ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} nx^n = \frac{x}{(1 - x)^2}$$

Thus, when $x = \frac{1}{e}$, we get the sum to be $\frac{\frac{1}{e}}{(1 - \frac1e)^2} = \frac{e}{(e - 1)^2}$

Alternatively without calculus:

Notice that $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{e^n} = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} S_k$, where $S_k = \displaystyle \sum_{n = k}^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^n}$

Then $S_k = \frac{1/e^k}{1 - 1/e}$ by geometric series formula. Again by geometric series formula, $\displaystyle \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} S_k = \frac{\frac{1/e}{1 - 1/e}}{1 - 1/e} = \frac{1/e}{(1 - 1/e)^2} = \frac{e}{(e - 1)^2}$

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}$, so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n = \frac{x}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x} - 1$.  I guess this mistake doesn't change the answer since you differentiate the series.

Comment: @SpamIAm true point. I'm more used to explaning this when it starts at $n = 0$. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 2):

Michael T. has posted the usual argument involving differentiation.  Here a probabilistic argument.

When you throw a die, you have a $1/6$ chance of getting an ace.  So average number of throws to get an ace is $6$.  Therefore
$$
6 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot \Pr(\text{number of throws}=n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\cdot\left(\frac56\right)^{n-1} \cdot\frac 1 6.
$$
If the probability of failure on each trial were $1/e$ instead of $5/6$, then the probability of success on each trial would be $1-(1/e)=(e-1)/e$ and the average number of trials to get a success would be the reciprocal of that: $e/(e-1)$.

So put
\begin{align}
1/e & \text{in place of }5/6, \\
(e-1)/e & \text{in place of }1/6, \\
e/(e-1) & \text{in place of }6.
\end{align}
We get
$$
\frac{e}{e-1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac 1 e\right)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{e-1}{e}.
$$
Divide both sides by $e-1$:
$$
\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{e^n}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Another approach which, perhaps, can be easier to apply in this particular case, because of the exponential: the $\;n$-th root test:

$$\sqrt[n]{\frac n{e^n}}=\frac{\sqrt[n] n}e\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac1e<1\implies\;\text{the series converges}$$

Comment: Though I wouldn't say that showing $n^{1/n} \to 1$ isn't as easy as showing that $\frac{n+1}{n} \to 1$. Yes, there are many well known (And relatively easy) ways to prove the former, but it may not be immediately obvious.